# Maintaining a (singleton) process with mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I have a python `web.py` app with *long (minutes) start-up time* that I'd like to host with in Apache with `mod_wsgi`.

The long-term answer may be "rewrite the app."  But **in the short term** I'd like to configure `mod_wsgi` to:

1. Use a single process to serve the app (I can do this with `WSGIDaemonProcess processes=1`), 
   *and*
2. Keep using that process without killing it off periodically

Is #2 doable?  Or, are there other stopgap solutions I can use to host this app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Don't restart Apache, don't set maximum-requests and don't change the code in the WSGI script file.

Are you saying that you are seeing restarts even when you leave Apache completely untouched?

And yes it sounds like you should be re-architecting your system. A web process that takes that long to startup is crazy.